# Testing controller expected 201 but was 400

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<201> but was:<400>

```
mockHttpServletResponse.getStatus() = 400
```

instead 201

**201 correct response is:**

> "string"

**This is my Controller.java**

```
@ApiOperation(value = "description")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @RequestMapping (value= {"/{country}/uois/getUserForOrganization"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUserForOrganization (
            @RequestBody UserForOrganization getUserForOrganizationType, 
            @ApiParam(required=true, value="Country Code (example: DE)")
            @PathVariable String country, 
            ) throws Exception {

        return service.getUserForOrganization(getUserForOrganizationType, country);ponse; 
    }
```

**This is my ControllerTest.java**

```
String countryString = "DE";

@MockBean
    RestTemplate restTemplate;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
        public void testControllerGetUserForOrganization() throws Exception {

            when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.contains("localhost:8080/" + countryString + "/uois/getUserForOrganization"),
                    Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(
                            new ResponseEntity<String>("\"string\"",
                                    HttpStatus.CREATED));

            String body = "\"string\"";

            URI uri = new URI("/" + countryString + "/uois/getUserForOrganization");

            MvcResult mvcResult = mvc
        .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).content(body))
                    .andReturn();

            MockHttpServletResponse mockHttpServletResponse = mvcResult.getResponse();

            assertEquals(201, mockHttpServletResponse.getStatus());
        }
```

Comment: `"String"` is not valid json.

Comment: "string" surely won't serialize to a UserForOrganization object.  Use a correct UserForOrganization json serialization as a body for the POST request.